# jQuery code won't run in content script, only on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

was just wondering if anyone had any input on why this code won't run in my content script for my chrome extension. The extension is setup properly, because I have code in the content script that DOES work, for some reason this code wont work at all. This code runs when I paste it into the console of the page that the code needs to run on.

Code:

```
function ucall(user) {
    window.open('test.com/userid=' + user, 'popup', 'width=600', 'height=600')
};
console.log("READY?")
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('group-comments')[0]
console.log(comments)
$(comments).on('hover', '.wall-comment', function () {
    var user = $(this).find('a')[1].href;
    user = user.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); console.log(user);
    console.log("do you hover bro?")
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'yellow' });
    $(this).click(function () {
        ucall(user)
    })
});
```

My theory behind why it might not work was that i thought the div's declared in the variable "comments", weren't being loaded in time for the code to execute. So then i tried to do `$(comments).ready(function(){//code here})`; That still didnt work. I'm pretty stumped. Also, all the code in my content script is inside of a:

```
$(document).ready(function(){// all content script code in here})
```

I just don't understand why this works in the console of the page itself, but not my chrome extension, also like I had mentioned, I have other code in this extension that does work, just stumped by this code.

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: Directly use `$('.wall-comment').hover(function () {` instead of `$(comments).on('hover', '.wall-comment', function () {`

Comment: @Fleischpfanzerl Nothing, the code works in the browser. The code doesnt work coming from a content script in my chrome extension. It doesn't make sense because I have code that does run in that content script, just not this code. I get no errors at all either.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef The reason i'm using $(comments).on('hover','.wall-comment') is because comments is a dynamic element. need to access '.wall-comment', as it loads in. The code works if i paste it in my browsers console, just not from my chrome extension.